# Apps scipt to add a event in calendar of type reminder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

I need to add an event of type Reminder via apps script. The reminder calendar appears to be very special. This calendar can neither be deleted not renamed.

Is there a way to create events using Google Apps Scripts into that calendar?

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested on [ask].

Comment: Hi Ruben, this is a question I am asking for. I found no pointers associated with it so far